# Change Tab with click the button using ABS

Tags: android, android-tabhost, actionbarsherlock

I make this code with base in ActionBarSherlokFragment Demo. I wish that when the user click the Button inside the Tab1 he be directed to Tab2 with this implementation because this implementation contains PageView. Is possible ?

Look the code Home:
http://pastebin.com/GU63pYM6

Event Button RelatorioFragment:

```
bt_vergrafico.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

Comment: I did otherwise. =D I did with Tab default